# How to detach a listener for a Firestore collection made with AngularFire?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Here's my observer that listens to a collection.

```js
interface Scientist {
  name?: string | null,
  born?: number | null,
  accomplishment?: string | null
};

export class AppComponent {
  scientist$: Observable<Scientist[]>;

 constructor(public firestore: Firestore) {
    this.scientist$ = collectionData(collection(firestore, 'scientists'));
  }
}
```

Works great but how do I detach the listener?

Answer (score 0):

`unsubscribe` is an interface for subscription, which is returned by `this.scientist$.subscribe(...)`. It seems currently `this.scientist$` is currently considered Observable instead.

Comment: Are you saying that listeners (or subscriptions) and observables aren't the same thing?